# How to merge multiple graphs of separate months, in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

```
library("dplyr")
library("rjson")
library("ggplot2")

json_file = "./sliceA.json" # Main data.
my.JSON = fromJSON(file=json_file, simplify = TRUE)

df = lapply(my.JSON, function(d) {
    data.frame(matrix(unlist(d), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
})

df = do.call(rbind, df)
names(df) = c("Year", "Month", "Day")

m = table(df$Month)
yr = table(df$Year)
d = table(df$Day)

yrChr = function(mon,year) {
    x = data.frame(ftable(df[df$Year == year,])[,c(1:31)])
    y = c(1:31) # This value was changed many times to try to adjust, but to no avail.

    ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() # The line throws an error, because both "x" and "y" are not appropriate.
    ggsave("Rplots.pdf")
}

ii = 0
while (ii < 12) {
    ii = ii+1
    yrChr(ii,2021)
}
```

"x" printed in console, with `Xn` indicating the number of accounts, and each row indicating those in a month, so (2,X9) would mean that in Feb., 128 accounts became members.
[image]

This is how some of how the graphs look like... from Jan. to Dec. they are all present.
[image]

The hope here is to combine all graphs into one, as so, to create a graph spanning the entire year.

My thought was to combine all columns of the separate data of months, which I did, but did not manage to succeed with plotting it (combined), as a `ts()`, the error thrown was, ‘‘multiple’’ series, which is apparently capped at ten. I returned to ‘‘ggplot2’’, but I have not apprehended it. I have not a clue of what should ease this.

(I am not experienced in R, barely seven days into it. Please, indicate more verbosely what is a must here, and do indicate if some prerequisite information is missing from this query, I shall reedit, and post, within good time.)

---

Sample data, as output by `dput(x)` in console:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
4L, 3L), X2 = c(2L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L
), X3 = c(7L, 39L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L), X4 = c(2L, 
16L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L), X5 = c(7L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L), X6 = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
9L, 9L, 15L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), X7 = c(3L, 11L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L), X8 = c(5L, 20L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L), X9 = c(2L, 128L, 4L, 12L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L), X10 = c(5L, 36L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 7L), X11 = c(7L, 31L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L), X12 = c(3L, 17L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 
4L, 8L), X13 = c(5L, 83L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
7L), X14 = c(2L, 51L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 0L), 
    X15 = c(2L, 44L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L), 
    X16 = c(5L, 37L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L), 
    X17 = c(5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L), 
    X18 = c(3L, 5L, 2L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L), 
    X19 = c(4L, 13L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L), 
    X20 = c(4L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L), 
    X21 = c(5L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 4L), 
    X22 = c(6L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L), 
    X23 = c(4L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L), 
    X24 = c(5L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L), 
    X25 = c(3L, 8L, 11L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 10L), 
    X26 = c(3L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), 
    X27 = c(15L, 13L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L), 
    X28 = c(10L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 4L), 
    X29 = c(2L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L), 
    X30 = c(4L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 7L), 
    X31 = c(12L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data used for plotting, ideally using `dput()`  rather than as an image since it makes it easier to help?

Comment: Perhaps `x` is not the actual object we should be testing? Since you're hoping to combine all monthly plots into one, I'm thinking `facet_*` or perhaps the `patchwork` package, but they would benefit from having the original data, likely `df`.

Comment: @r2evans, `df` is composed of three col., the first is the year (I am only interested in instances where the year is 2021), and the latter two are the month and day; each row represents an instance of a new membership (at that time). (I do not know what is the benefit of `patchwork`, in general.)

Comment: Do you want the twelve months on separate canvases but all in one pdf page, or do you think all months on one plot, using color to distinguish between the months?

Comment: @r2evans, I would rather have them blend contagiously.

Comment: Do you mean contiguously, continuously, or consecutively? I've not heard of data blending [contagiously](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/contagiously) ... ;-)

Comment: @r2evans, oh yes. Yes. I meant, ‘‘contiguously,’’ (as thought it were one line) and it was ‘‘corrected,’’ beyond my will. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once solution using `facet_wrap()` from the {ggplot2} package to create 12 small plots (one for each month), and align them next to each other to show the whole year:

```r
library(tidyverse)
# format the data to long format
plot_data <- x %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "month") %>%
  mutate(month = month.abb[as.numeric(month)],
         month = factor(month, levels = month.abb)) %>% # use month name
  pivot_longer(cols = -month, names_to = "day") %>% # long format
  mutate(day = parse_number(day)) # get rid of X at start

# create the line plots
ggplot(plot_data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = day, y = value), colour = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~month, nrow = 1) + # plot for each month
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: line chart]

Comment: Thank you, Nrennie! I shall try this, and amend it thereafter. Hopefully, I improve in R, so that I can do much more with less prompts for ‘‘help([instert function])’’ every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

another approach, playing with {[lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/)} features and facets:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d |> ## d being your dataframe
  mutate(month = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-month,
               names_to = 'day_of_month',
               values_to = 'accounts'
               ) |>
  mutate(the_date = ymd(sprintf('2023/%s/%s',
                                gsub('X', '', month), day_of_month))
         ) |>
  filter(!is.na(the_date)) |>
  dplyr::select(the_date, month, accounts) |>
  ggplot(aes(the_date, accounts)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ lubridate::quarter(the_date), scales = 'free_x')
```

[image: accounts facetted per quarter]

(btw, looks like sales data for Valentine's gifts)

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion. Oh yes, now that I think of it. I have one question though, what is `pivot_longer()`?

Comment: a convenience function to reshape your data from wide (one column per day, in your case) to long (one column for all days): https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html , in line with the "tidy data" approach: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html